TypeError, can't handle two datatypes
I can't convert received HLS bytes into some datatype that openAI whisper can process.
Here I've got HLS via streamlink and I need some way to convert audio part of this HLS-bytes into correct numpy.ndarray.
import streamlink

link_list = streamlink.streams("TWITCH.TV LINK HERE")
streamobj = link_list['worst']
fd = streamobj.open()`

I can save it to mp3 file with simple thing like this:
with open('test.mp3', 'wb') as file:
    while True:
        data = fd.read(1024) #btw idk what is that const 1024 from streamlink quickstart
        if not data:
            break
        file.write(data)

file.close()
fd.close()`

And now I want to put this audio (bytes, but I can save it, it's not corrupt I think) into the openai whisper model to transcribe this like
try:
    with open("new_test.mp3", "wb") as file:
        while True:
            data = fd.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            result = model.transcribe(data)
            print(result)
            file.write(data)
finally:
    fd.close()
    file.close()

I need to decode bytes in realtime and put it into model without saving any file.
It doesn't work in any way I tried:

I've tried to convert data to numpy.ndarray
I tried to convert this using soundfile
I tried to split audio and video from data with ffmpeg (didn't tried properly, actually)


Can you provide the full error message for me please?

Instead of transcribing the audio as you go, try transcribing the audio after it has been saved to a file.
try:
    with open("new_test.mp3", "wb") as file:
    while True:
        data = fd.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        file.write(data)
finally:
    fd.close()
    file.close()
    result = model.transcribe("new_test.mp3")
    print(result["text"])

model.transcribe(data) does not take sound data, it takes the sound file itself, and also, use result["text"] instead of just result.

yeah, but i need to ?decode bytes in realtime? and put it into model. without saving any file because of high impact of IO instructions on performance

It's easier for me to post this as an answer than as a comment. It looks like you could just create a BytesIO buffer and pass it straight into the model. Could you try:
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO(fd.read(1024))
result = model.transcribe(buffer)

# try result = model.transcribe(buffer.getvalue()) if the above doesn't work.

This should work in concept.

Found a solution. In my case, I've got audio bytes from HLS (use ffmpeg for this read). After converted it to numpy.ndarray, if I put a numpy.ndarray, the source audio (which i converted to ndarray) should have following parameters (theyre hardcoded or smth): sample rate = 16000, mono, 2bytes per sample.
Code that works in my case looks like this:
    raw_audio = proc.stdout.read(32000) # reading bytes from ffmpeg
    
    audio_data = np.frombuffer(raw_audio, dtype=np.int16)
    
    audio_segment = AudioSegment(
        data=raw_audio,
        sample_width=2,
        frame_rate=16000,
        channels=1
    ) # converting bytes to audio with parameters that model can process

    raw_audio_mono = audio_segment.raw_data
    audio_data = np.frombuffer(raw_audio_mono, dtype=np.int16)
    float_audio = audio_data.astype(np.float32) / 32768.0

    result = model.transcribe(float_audio)

